# Для нестатического поля требуется ссылка на объект c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Для нестатического поля требуется ссылка на объект c#
вот часть кода:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Form2.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //ругается на Form2.openFileDialog1
            {
                img = Image.FromFile(Form2.openFileDialog1.FileName); //ругается на Form2.openFileDialog1
                pictureBox1.Image = img;
            }

            Byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            img = Image.FromStream(ms);
            pictureBox1.Image = img;
        }
```

Comment: На какую именно строку ругается?

Comment: где указывается путь к Form2.openFileDialog1

Comment: Как называется класс в котором находится этот код? `Form2` это другая форма или та же в которой находится `pictureBox1`?

Comment: да, всё верно. Form2 это другая форма,
а pictureBox находится вообще в Form9

Answer (score 1):

`Form2` - название класса. Здесь нужно название переменной или вообще ничего не нужно, если этот диалог на той же форме, чей код.

---

```
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    ...

        if (form2.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
        {
            img = form2.Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

---

Или положите `OpenFileDialog` на `Form9`, тогда `Form2` не понадобится.

```
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
        {
            img = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

Comment: pictureBox вообще находится в Form9, а openFileDialog прикреплен к Form2

Comment: мне надо, чтобы он в новой форме отображал картинку из БД

Comment: @ghivn Какой БД? При чем здесь БД?